# Why can't I update a foreign field on my table?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using Ormlite and I have an object that has a foreign field.

The said object also has getters and setters for it's fields.

```
public class Object {

   @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
   private Object2 foreignField;

   Object() {

   }

   public Object2 getForeignField(){ return foreignField; }

   public void setForeignField(Object2 foreignField){ 
       this.foreignField = foreignField; 
   }
}
```

So I assumed that when I call :

```
Object testObject;
Object2 testObject2;

testObject.setForeignField(testObject2);
getDao.update(testObject);
```

It will automatically update the `testObject` in the database with the new foreignfield's id, but my table is not updating.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT :
By reading the actual documentation on Ormlite, the `update(Object)` method will not update any foreign objects or foreign collections.

http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#update(T)

`NOTE: This will not save changes made to foreign objects or to foreign collections.`

And now because of that, how do I update a foreign object on a table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you update a foreign field in Ormlite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795538/how-do-you-update-a-foreign-field-in-ormlite)

Answer (score 0):

> It will automatically update the testObject in the database with the new foreignfield's id, but my table is not updating.

It certainly should be.

The `update(...)` call doesn't compare the object with the database so a SQL `UPDATE` statement *will* be made.  Have you tried [turning on ORMLite logging](http://ormlite.com/docs/logging)?

If it is updating the `Object` with the same id from the `Object2 foreignField` then maybe that id is the same?  When you call `testObject.setForeignField(testObject2)`, the `testObject2` should already have been created in the `Object2` table.  It needs to have an appropriate `id` field which is was gets stored in the `Object` table.

If you provide more details about the id field values and what the database has before and after the update, I may be able to help more.