# How do you update a foreign field in Ormlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, ormlite

I tried `update(Object)`, `update(PreparedUpdate)`, `executeRaw(String)`, `updateRaw(String)`, and even tried directly using the helper class then using `getData(String query)`. But my table's foreign field is still not updated. Any thoughts why this is happening?

Comment: Can you explain this more?  I don't think I fully understand.  Can you show the data before and after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I am using the method `update(Object)` on other methods while passing an outdated instance of the object I am trying to update. So once I use the actual `update(PreparedUpdate)` method, I am reverting the object back to its original state as some other method is using `update(outdated Object)`